# mysql transaction order - Trigger not working in Production

Tags: php, mysql-5.5

I am using PHP to insert into MYSQL database. There is a trigger BEFORE INSERT ON table1. Then, I insert BULK data into MYSQL table2. The insert query for table2 is inside PHP while loop. Here is the order of transaction and trigger:

```
START TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO TABLE1 <-TRIGGER below

while(INSERT INTO TABLE2) // Comment: One INSERT per row

COMMIT
```

------------- TRIGGER NOT WORKING -----------------

```
delimiter $$

CREATE
TRIGGER `sample`.`new_gm_sequence`
BEFORE INSERT ON `sample`.`frtgoodsmovement`
FOR EACH ROW
begin 
declare wno     varchar(20);

select concat(numberprefix, cast(slno+1 as char)) into wno
from   frtnumbercontrol
where  codetype     = 'GMTY'
and    code         = new.gmtype
and    new.gmdate between frdate and todate;

set new.gmno = wno;   

update frtnumbercontrol set slno = slno+1
where  codetype     = 'GMTY'
and    code         = new.gmtype
and    new.gmdate between frdate and todate;

end
$$
```

`gmno` in the above trigger is the field to be autogenerated in table1(frtgoodsmovement). It is not working in Production but WORKING IN NON-PRODUCTION. The field results for table2 are coming another table.

Here is a screenshot:https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgNXR.jpg

During manual data entry, GM No is generating. What could be the issue?

Note: It takes around 1sec to make INSERTs of 100 records. Should I make it faster? Then the trigger will work with PHP BULK INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

Will MySql Lock Table solve this issue? 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html

```
LOCK TABLES
    tbl_name [[AS] alias] lock_type
    [, tbl_name [[AS] alias] lock_type] ...

lock_type:
    READ [LOCAL]
  | [LOW_PRIORITY] WRITE

UNLOCK TABLES
```